# AWS S3 - Static website hosting - Redirection rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html#configure-bucket-as-website-routing-rule-syntax

shows some optional Redirection Rules. E.g.

[image]

whereas the UI I see does not:

[image]

Any suggestions as to why there's a difference?

Answer (score 1):

In the first screenshot **Use this bucket to host a website** is selected. In the second screenshot **Redirect requests** is selected. Different options are available based on the bucket configuration you select.